# using Angular to populate object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a HTML and JS Script.

I would like to populate the values of my objects in the second controller with text field inputs from my html page, also have a add button to populate the objects on click and change the slot number accordingly.

So far I can read the objects, how do I add the value from my html on click and have the slot number increment by one each time?

**Script**

```
.controller('second', function($scope) {
$scope.items = {
    "c_name": "Name of the campaign",
    "max_slots": 1,
    "d_text": ["age", "gender", "name"],
    "slots": [
        {
            "slot_id": 1,
            "path_image": "path",
            "base_image": "base 64 image",
            "age": 25,
            "gender": "your Gender",
            "name": "your name"
        }
    ]
}

});
```

**HTML**

```
        <div ng-controller="second">
   <div ng-repeat="(key, values) in items">
  {{key}}
  <div ng-repeat="item in values">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
                  <!-- each time click add increment slot number -->
                  <button>add</button>
```

Comment: Using `ng-click` directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click` directive to call controller function in your view.

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.items.slots.push(
        { 
            // Something 
        }
    );
}
```